# How to get the data in front end when API calling returning data in [[101,4],[102,2],[103,1],[104,1],[105,1],[108,1],[109,1]] without key value pair?

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart

When I am calling API its giving data in [[101,4],[102,2],[103,1],[104,1],[105,1],[108,1],[109,1]] format which is only value. Is there any solution that how to get this data in UI in flutter?
Previously I have worked with below type of data coming from API.In this data can be accessed using key name but how to access value in [[101,4],[102,2],[103,1],[104,1],[105,1],[108,1],[109,1]] format when there is no key to access value in Flutter?
[{"activityId":101,"docId":90,"status":1},{"activityId":101,"docId":100,"status":0},{"activityId":101,"docId":159,"status":0},{"activityId":101,"docId":201,"status":0},{"activityId":1784,"docId":123,"status":1}]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like basic `List<List<int>>` so if data is  [[101,4],[102,2],[103,1],[104,1],[105,1],[108,1],[109,1]] let's say you want to **access number 4** from the start of the message you'd need to **access it like**:

```
final response = <List<int>> [[101,4],[102,2],[103,1],[104,1],[105,1],[108,1],[109,1]]

int four = response[0][1];

print('$four')
```

in terminal would print value 4